# Where this file getting called vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Adminhtml/Edit.php in Magento 2.2.6?

Tags: magento, magento2

For the admin customer view page, Magento used UI form as "customer_form". I want to know how the other tabs are getting called like "Orders", "Wish list", "Newsletter". These are not UI forms or UI grid.

Please help me, how these tabs are implemented in customer view/edit page.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Tab/` and then for example `Newsletter.php`. Magento UI is implemented there via

```
use Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface;
```

and

```
class Newsletter extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements TabInterface
```

You can find the functions for the tab in that class.